# Sending an image from android client to google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm writing a mobile android application which send an image (as Base64 encoded byte array) to a Google app engine server.
On the server I want to supply the image I got from the client to a third party module which expects it to be a Bitmap.
The problem is that I can't find a way to get create an image from the encoded byte array on GAE.
Each thing I tried failed due to app engine restrictions: "x is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the Image API setImageData method, which takes a byte array of image data to create an Image object that can be used with the rest of the image APIs?

Comment: I tried to create the image using the Image API (com.google.appengine.api.images.Image), but the other module that expects that image, expect it to be Bitmap/JPEG. Any thoughts about how can I transform the Image instance to one of these formats?

Answer (score 0):

That Google App Engine doesn't support some javax classes.

Would imageIO class if available solves your problem? then the possible answer is as follows:

1. Download the classes of ImageIO class(see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810488/where-can-i-download-original-java-packages-and-add-to-my-project) to know how)
2. create your own jar file with those class files
3. Add the jar file to your /WEB-INF/lib/ folder
4. Use the ImageIO class in your application logic

Does this solutions seems to work?